# How to show $\dim X\lt\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

How to show $\dim X\lt\infty$ ?

Let B the open unit ball in a normed space $X$, $L$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $X$. Suppose that for some $N$ with $N\ge 1$ we have :

$N B\subset (N-1)B + L$. Then prove $\dim X\lt\infty$.

Could you please help me with this question

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $X=L$. Start by picking a point $x$ in $X$ with $\|x\|=1$, then consider the point $(N-1/2)x \in NB\backslash (N-1)B$. What can you conclude about the unit ball of $X$? What does this imply?

Comment: I think it means we can represent points of the space by elements of unit ball. That is, span of the unit ball is the whloe space. but still cannot conclude.

Comment: Observe that the point $(N-1/2)x$ is in $NB$, but not in $(N-1)B$. By our assumption, this means that $(N-1/2)x \in L$, and hence $x \in L$, by scaling back down. So the unit ball of $X$ is fully contained in $L$.

Comment: so X is contained in L by $X=\cup n.unitball$ ? could you please explain how  $(N-1/2)x\in L$ implies $x\in L$

Comment: $L$ is a subspace, so closed under scalar multiplication. You can multiply by $\frac{1}{N-1/2}$ and it will still be in $L$.